# How to solve Woocommerce Memory Limit

Tags: php, plugins, limit

I have Woocommerce set up to run on WP multi-site with my PHP Memory Limit set to 256M in the php.ini

I also have in my wp-congif.php

```
define("WP_MEMORY_LIMIT", 128);
```

However Woocommerce shows the following "WP Memory Limit: 12 B - We recommend setting memory to at least 64MB."

How can I solve this

Comment: The correct syntax is define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try toying with the [max memory limit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP). I think it's far more likely you are on an [EIG host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_International_Group) and throttled to a 64mb limit.

Oh one more thing, it's

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
```

Comment: I'm not an on EIG host however adding the correct syntax help. thanks

Comment: Glad it was useful to you. I only mentioned EIG because back in 2013 they barely gave an account enough RAM to load WordPress for a single user.